# Hostinger web share shoting giving back 403 forbidden error

Tags: laravel, deployment, web-hosting, http-status-code-403

I am trying to deploy my laravel project through git hub on hostinger. The deployement through git actually work out and all the files are installed in subdomain where I want to deploy the project which is in public_html/absolute. The deployment on the surface installed all the files including the files in the public folder to the absolute subfolder. But when I got to the link https://coffeesojava.xyz/absolute/ it says 403 Forbidden, Access to this resource on the server is denied!. I am not sure what went wrong.

public_html/absolute/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Copy the .htacces file from the public folder and paste it outside of the public folder
2. Rename server.php to index.php

Comment: Thnaks for helping, but when I go into the domain.com/sub-domain link it says the page does not work

Comment: enable debugger on the laravel then you can see the errors

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I replace true in APP_DEBUG of .env file and then realized I forgot to do database connection. You really saved me sir. Sorry to ask you something again. The images inside the public folder of the server are not loading. Although the website runs. Can you tell me what should I do? Thank you so much for helping me truly!

Comment: Let me know if are you using assets() function to loading CSS and JS Like this : 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('assets/style.css') }}">