Laravel deploy on Hostinger
I have problems to deploy my Laravel project on a subdomain on Hostinger
I'm new to deployment and recently purchased a "Business Web Hosting" plan on Hostinger to host my projects, as it was recommended by various developer YouTubers.
I encountered some issues while trying to deploy my Laravel project, so I followed this guide by The Codeholic. The first problem I faced was that I couldn't run npm since Node.js is not installed on this shared hosting. Consequently, I had to remove /public/build from .gitignore, and this allowed me to proceed.
However, my current issue is as follows: I created a subdomain because I wanted to set up a testing environment, and Hostinger automatically created it within the public_html folder of my main project. The path is as follows: /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html/subdomain.
Here, I cloned the project again and followed all the steps outlined in the video, but I'm only getting a 403 error. The only page I'm able to see is the default.php (default of Hostinger). As soon as I delete that file, I encounter a 403 error again. Can someone please assist me with this issue?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you try the steps given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341832/hostinger-web-share-shoting-giving-back-403-forbidden-error

Still have the problem...project in the domain works, but the subdomain doesn't.
Is the subdomain path right? in the public_html folder of the main domain?
the pathof the main project is this:
/home/userxxxxxx/domains/mysite.it/
while the subdomain is:
/home/userxxxxxx/domains/mysite.it/public_html/mysite-test
